# How to use the async pipe with an Observable<ApiResponse>

Tags: angular, asynchronous, pipe

Typescript:

```
getMyList(): Observable<ApiResponse> {
    return this.http.get<ApiResponse>(this.myListUrl);
  }

this.myList = getMyList();
```

HTML:

```
<ng-select [items]="myList | async">
```

```
The List: 
Id: 1, Name: foo; Id: 2, Name: bar; ...
```

Earlier I did something like this, but this does not work async (with the pipe):

```
getList().subscribe(data => {
   data.result.forEach(entry => {
      this.myList.push(entry.Name);
   });
});
```

I read something with mapping the Observable ApiResponse to an Observable MyList, but I have no idea how to do this. Looking for advice

Comment: It looks good as far as I can see, what is the problem? Is the data not showing up? Do you get any error messages in the console? Are you sure that the ng-select items accepts data that looks like the data you get from your API request?

Comment: The data is showing up sometimes. Not consistently, I think, this is because sometimes the api-call is faster than the dom-buildup and sometimes slower.

Comment: To me that theory sounds a bit strange, but I have been wrong before. You could add a console log at the end of your observable, then you would see in the console if the data is actually returned every time. Like this: this.http.get<ApiResponse>(this.myListUrl). pipe(tap(console.log));

Comment: Did it. The data is returned every time...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find here a [stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-60061787-angular-bcs3bh) on how to use `HttpClient`, `Observable` and `async` pipe.

Please may I suggest you some best practices :

- Use `$` after your observable variable name to clearly distinguish it from other non observable variable. You should use `async` pipe with observable.
- Needless to make a subscription to fill an array. Observables are very powerful with `async` pipe.
- Distinguish with your model the `API` response, and the item model in inside. (if it's the case). You can see in my example, that `get` returns a `ApiResponse` model, but after we are retrieving an array of `ApiItem`.

Update:

`HttpClient.get` returns an Observable. It's like a pipeline. You can then define a chain of operators, and each time a data is emitted, it will pass througth this pipeline, in order to be transformed.
In this example, api returns a `ApiResponse` object, with one unique property : an array of ApiItem. 
`map` operator transforms the input value. Here, it returns the list of items.

You will find a lot of good tutorials about Observables and pipe operators. For example [HTTP Example with Observables](https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/http/http-with-observables/) from [Asim](https://twitter.com/jawache).

Hope this could help you a little.

Comment: Yes! That really help, but can you explain further what 
(map(response => response.items) does? where comes the first and the second response from?

Comment: I have a structure like this: `export class ApiResponse { status: number; message: number;  result: any; }` `export class myList{ id: number; name: string; }`

Comment: solved it myself. `this.myList$ = this.apiService.getMyList().pipe(map(result => result.result));` Thanks a lot for that great stackblitz demo! It helped a lot!